# Terraform Azure disk attachment based on a variable

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

we have below resource creation and I need to control only the creating of this orahome resource based on `var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk` when its false it should not create and when true it should create.

```
`resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "dbhome" {
      count                = var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk ? 1 : 0
      name                 = "${local.db_server_name}-orahome-0"
      location             = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
      resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
      create_option        = "Empty"
      disk_size_gb         = var.dbdisksize_dbhome
      zones                = local.availability_zone
    }`
```

So by adding the line `count = var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk ? 1 : 0` its hapenning properly and fine.Please correct if this method also not correct.

Problem is, while VM creation its still trying to attached that disk and find a managed_disk_id even I put `count = var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk ? 1 : 0` on it. I need to fully ignore that disk creation and attachment and continue but other disk should proceed as same as earlier.

```
`resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "oracle19c" {
      name                             = local.db_server_name
      location                         = azurerm_network_interface.nic.location
      resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      network_interface_ids            = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
      vm_size                          = contains(var.vm_nonsupported_regions, var.region) ? var.dbvmsize_fallback : var.dbvmsize
      delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
      delete_data_disks_on_termination = true
      
      storage_data_disk {
        count           = var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk ? 1 : 0
        name            = "${local.db_server_name}-orahome-0"
        caching         = "ReadOnly"
        managed_disk_id = azurerm_managed_disk.dbhome.id
        create_option   = "Attach"
        lun             = 1
        disk_size_gb    = var.dbdisksize_dbhome
      }
    }`
```

I added `count = var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk ? 1 : 0` in azurerm_managed_disk creation and also attachment of that disk. but no luck with the main requirment

Comment: You are applying the condition correctly, are you sure that the value for the variable azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk is "false"? please check the default value in your variable.tf file or your variable.tfvars file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to control only the creating of this orahome resourcebasedon`var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk` when its false it should not create and when true it should create.
>
> By using for_each, we can resolve the same problem.

The managed disk is created, and the data disk is attached. If `var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk` is `false`, neither the managed disk is created nor the data disk is attached. The use of the `for_each` block helps control the number of instances based on the condition.

I am trying to create an `Azure VM` with a managed data disk using the following code.

```
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    variable "azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk" {
      type    = bool
      default = true  
    }
    variable "dbdisksize_dbhome" {
      type    = number
      default = 128
    }
    variable "dbvmsize" {
      type    = string
      default = "Standard_DS2_v2"  
    }
    variable "dbvmsize_fallback" {
      type    = string
      default = "Standard_DS1_v2"  
    }
    locals {
      db_server_name   = "my-db-server"  
      availability_zone = ["1"]  
    }
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "vm-resources"
      location = "East US"
    }
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
      name                = "vm-network"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
      name                 = "internal"
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
      address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
      depends_on = [ azurerm_virtual_network.main ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
      name                = "vm-nic"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      ip_configuration {
        name                          = "testconfiguration1"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
      }
      depends_on = [ azurerm_subnet.internal ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "dbhome" {
      count                = var.azure_db_server_create_orahome_disk ? 1 : 0
      name                 = "${local.db_server_name}-orahome-0"
      location             = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
      create_option        = "Empty"
      disk_size_gb         = var.dbdisksize_dbhome
      depends_on = [ azurerm_network_interface.main ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "oracle19c" {
      name                             = "venkatvm1"
      location                         = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name              = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      network_interface_ids            = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
      vm_size                          = "Standard_D8s_v3"
      delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
      delete_data_disks_on_termination = true
    
     storage_os_disk {
        name              = "vm-os-disk"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
        disk_size_gb      = 64
      }
    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "SUSE"
        offer     = "sles-sap-12-sp5"
        sku       = "gen1"
        version   = "latest"
      }
      dynamic "storage_data_disk" {
        for_each = azurerm_managed_disk.dbhome
        content {
          name              = "${local.db_server_name}-orahome-0"
          caching           = "None"
          managed_disk_id   = try(storage_data_disk.value.id, null)
          create_option     = "Attach"
        # managed_disk_type = ""
          lun             = 1
          disk_size_gb    = var.dbdisksize_dbhome
        }
      }
    
      os_profile {
        computer_name  = "venakt-vm"
        admin_username = "Admin"
        admin_password = "Pa$$word@123$"
      }
    
      os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = false
      }
    }
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

When I set `default = true`, a managed disk is created and attached to the VM as below.

[image]

When I set `default = false`, a managed disk is not created

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resloved by making dynamic "storage_data_disk" {} and also with for_each inside that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).